# Filtering related fields in django's annotate() feature

Tags: django

The Django documentation gives examples for [using annotate() to produce aggregate results](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates) based on related fields of a QuerySet (i.e., using joins in annotate()).

A simplified example from the docs is for instance `Store.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('books__price'))`, where books is a ManyToMany field of Store to Book and price is a field of Book.

To continue this example, how would I generate an annotated QuerySet of Store objects with the lowest prices not for all books in the store, but just for books with "author='William Shakespeare'"?  In other words, how do I filter the related fields used to calculate the aggregate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) explains how to do this:

```
Store.objects.filter(books__author='William Shakespeare').annotate(
                     min_price=Min('books__price'))
```

As that link notes, the order of filter and annotate matters here - because you want to only count books that match the filter in the annotation, the filter must come first.

Comment: Oh, I see.  This won't just filter out stores without books by Shakespeare, but it'll also affect the subset of books the annotation runs on.  Thank you!